# why custom-build python 2.7.x in sublime text 3.x doesn't run accordingly

Tags: sublimetext3, python-2.x

```
def a(x):
    assert x>0,'invalid argument'
    print 'wow'

a(2)
a(0)
```

this should first print "wow" and then it should raise an exception but instead it prints.The "wow" is splited as "wo" before "assert x>0" and after "AssertionError" on third last line and it keeps changing unpredictly but not once before "Traceback":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Books\Python\think python\assert.py", line 6, in <module>
    a(0)
  File "E:\Books\Python\think python\assert.py", line 2, in a
wo    assert x>0,'invalid argument'
AssertionErrorw
: invalid argument
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

My sublime build is:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Python27\\python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

Comment: which build version of ST are you using?

Comment: ST Build 3143 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

When Sublime launches an external program (such as when you run a build and it runs `python`), it starts two background threads that capture the output of the `stdout` and `stderr` handles of the program that it's running so that it can display it in the build panel.

Sublime makes sure that only one of those two threads can add data to the output panel at any point, but the data captured by each thread is unbuffered in any way, so as soon as any data appears at the output handle it's queued up for appending to the output panel.

The reason you see this happening is because the print statement sends output to `stdout`, but exceptions are written to `stderr`. Due to the nature of multi threaded programs, it's indeterminate which of the two threads might capture it's output first, which means that the output of the two handles mix in apparently random ways.

I would imagine that Sublime works this way because if it buffered output to lines by default, programs that generate partial lines at a time would appear to not be running at all.

In practice, while annoying this should not have too much of a deleterious effect on things since generally speaking `stdout` is for regular output and `stderr` is for error messages, so if both need to be used something untoward is already happening.

It's also possible to create your own custom build `target` that mimics what `exec` does except with line buffering, in case such a thing is a solid requirement.

---

As further explanation for the above (and an example of running a program with line buffering), here is an example Python program that demonstrates more clearly what's happening here. Once a second for 10 seconds this generates a `.` to `stdout` and a `-` to `stderr`, and then once the 10 seconds has elapsed, it sends a newline to each handle in turn.

```python
import sys
import time

for _ in range(0,10):
    sys.stdout.write(".")
    sys.stderr.write("-")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stderr.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stderr.write("\n")
```

When I run the program with the default `Python.sublime-build`, I end up with this:

```
.--.-..-.--.-.-.-.-.

[Finished in 10.1s]
```

This demonstrates that not only does the output of `stderr` and `stdout` blend together, it also does it in weirdly indeterminate ways caused by the multi-threaded nature of the capture.

For example you might expect the output to come out as an alternating series like `.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-`, but it doesn't; although there are 10 of each item, they don't appear in the same order that we printed them out because the order that each thread gets scheduled to run and notices that there is output to add to the panel is indeterminate.

As I mentioned above, you can create your own custom build target that does what the `exec` command does with the exception of holding data in an intermediate buffer and only releasing it to the output panel lines at a time instead of as it appears, which will stop this from happening.

---

***Important Note***: Doing line buffering like this doesn't stop the data from `stderr` and `stdout` from interleaving, it just ensures that the data interleaves whole lines at a time instead of going all "alien chest burster" on each other mid-line. To truly stop the interleave you need to send each handle to a different location (like two panels or sending `stderr` to the console).

---

The full code for something like this is too lengthy to add to an SO answer, so for demonstration purposes I've put the code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/OdatNurd/f4156d4b16b10772263560568775e5b1). Revision 1 is the base version of the files and revision 2 is the modified versions for buffering, so you can see [the differences between the two](https://gist.github.com/OdatNurd/f4156d4b16b10772263560568775e5b1/revisions?diff=split) to better understand the change.

The default `exec` command captures output from `stderr` and `stdout` and sends it directly to the output panel once it's received; as the data arrives at the output panel the command normalizes the line end characters to what Sublime expects to see (for Windows/Mac computers), then adds it to the panel.

The modified version reads the data into a temporary buffer and does the newline normalization right away, then only forwards along any whole lines that it has accumulated, leaving the rest of the data for the next time around. Once the output is finished, any remaining data is sent to the buffer so that everything gets displayed.

In order to use the new target, the `sublime-build` file has to have a `target` argument added to tell Sublime to use a command other than `exec`. The Gist has an example of that for the default `Python.sublime-build`, along with an extra key to add to allow the `Cancel Build` functionality to work with the custom target.

With the modified build in place, the output of the program becomes this:

```
----------
..........
[Finished in 10.1s]
```

Note that a side effect of this is that now you see nothing at all in the build panel for 10 seconds and then all of the output appears all at once, since it can't appear until it's complete; this sort of thing is likely the reason why Sublime doesn't do this by default.

As mentioned above, this doesn't stop the data from interleaving, it just controls how it happens so it happens a line at a time. It's still indeterminate which of the `stdout` and `stderr` lines appears first.

If you like, you can modify the code starting at line 169 from this:

```python
# Accumulate data into our buffer and only let full lines
# through to the output panel.
if self.listener:
    pBuffer += data
    nPos = pBuffer.rfind("\n")
    if nPos >= 0:
        self.listener.on_data(self, pBuffer[:nPos+1])
        pBuffer = pBuffer[nPos+1:]
```

To this:

```python
# Accumulate data into our buffer and only let full lines
# through to the output panel; stderr data is held until the
# handle is closed below.
if self.listener:
    pBuffer += data
    if execute_finished:
        nPos = pBuffer.rfind("\n")
        if nPos >= 0:
            self.listener.on_data(self, pBuffer[:nPos+1])
            pBuffer = pBuffer[nPos+1:]
```

That modifies things so that the data for `stderr` is stored in a buffer but not released to the output panel until after the program terminates.

Doing that will ensure that there's no interleave, but it also stops you from seeing errors at the point at which they occurred. It also makes it impossible to see errors as they happen if your program is long running and can cause memory usage to increase if there is a lot of error output being buffered but not displayed.

As such I wouldn't recommend this unless you're doing something like running short lived programs where it's less intrusive to have the errors appear at the end.

Comment: thanks a lot. but can u tell me more about custom build target

Comment: I've added more information, including a sample of doing exactly this (in an external gist due to code size). Instructions on how to use the plugin are in a comment at the bottom of the gist if you're interested.