# Sublime Text realtime program output

Tags: sublimetext3

When running your application over ST's build system it displays the console output only once the application has exited, it also posts the time it took to finish.
Is there a way to show the output in realtime, like a normal console would?

```
cout < text < endl;
[do something for 5 secs];
```

After 5secs:

```
text
[Finished in 5.0s]
```

Comment: Sublime doesn't buffer output: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296736/how-to-remove-output-buffering-when-running-python-in-sublime-text-3). If your program works as you expect from the terminal but not in a build, then the runtime is deciding it needs to buffer `stdout` and you need to either resolve that or manually flush the stream.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OdatNurd's comment explained it perfectly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861163/sublime-text-realtime-program-output?noredirect=1#comment88729787_50861163)
Buffering was indeed the culprit. I have never came in contact with the whole topic of how characters are buffered and flushed to outputs. Implementing a console is not as straight forward as I thought.
In C setting

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

once or calling

```
fflush(stdout); (which is a bit cleaner)
```

after every printf solved everything!